# VBA Convert String to Date using periods as date seperators

Tags: vba

I have tried the following but not working,

```
Dim my_date_string As String
Dim my_date_date As Date

my_date_string = "22.10.2020"
my_date_date = CDate(my_date_string)

Debug.Print my_date_string
Debug.Print my_date_date
```

Also tried with,

```
my_date_date = Format(my_date_string, "DD.MM.YYYY")
```

Comment: `my_date_date = CDate(Replace(my_date_string, ".", "/"))`

Comment: You try converting string to date... Your code works only with regionalization involving that type of data (in the string) as default. Doing what @braX recommended works in all cases, anyhow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CDate` does not understand periods as separators.

If you need them to be periods in your `String` variable for some reason, just replace them like this:

```
my_date_date = CDate(Replace(my_date_string, ".", "/"))
```

If your variable does not have periods in it, the `Replace` function will simply do nothing.